# How to run psmouse with "proto=imps" on startup?

Tags: kernel, startup-applications

I have ubuntu 16.04.
I want to add

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

to my startup applications.

I added it succesfully but it isn't running with the startup.

I think because of the password requirement.

Please help me as I want it to run along with start of my laptop.

Is there any other way or is there a way to fulfill my above requirements?
Please let me know....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

stops `psmouse` and starts it with `proto=imps` option.

Startup applications is a wrong way to set options for kernel modules.

The correct way to achieve the desired result is to use `modprobe.d` config files.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf <<< "options psmouse proto=imps"
```

and reboot.

That will create the `psmouse.conf` file and `psmouse` will start with the desired option.

Comment: Comment was succesful , but didn't run with the startup

Comment: Can you give an another way?

Comment: Are you sure you've done it correctly? Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf` to your question.